# How to use ng-template in p-tree when value have "type" property

Tags: primeng

ng-template starts working after I removed "type" property from data that I'm passing to `p-tree` how can I fix it up? I guess there is something that I'm doing wrong cause "type" is one of TreeNode properties

**[TreeNode.ts](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/common/treenode.ts)**

```
export interface TreeNode {
    label?: string;
    data?: any;
    icon?: any;
    expandedIcon?: any;
    collapsedIcon?: any;
    children?: TreeNode[];
    leaf?: boolean;
    expanded?: boolean;
    type?: string;
    parent?: TreeNode;
    partialSelected?: boolean;
    styleClass?: string;
    draggable?: boolean;
    droppable?: boolean;
    selectable?: boolean;
}
```

I provide an example you can see it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BksBGUA1iMrEruyK4j0e?p=preview)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your Plnkr, the only time you need to use type is when you are using multiple templates.  For example, you have a `type` of 'test'.  To use that, you would add a template as follows (note the `pTemplate` of the second ngTemplate):

```
<p-tree [value]="filesTree6">
    <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
        <input [(ngModel)]="node.label" type="text" style="width:100%">
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-node pTemplate="test">
        <h3>{{node.label}}</h3>
    </ng-template>
</p-tree>
```